# Stored procedure sin variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda resulta que estoy creando un procdimiento almacenado con varios if en donde especifico que de las 5 variables son minimo necesarias 2 como puedo hacer para ejecutar este sin necesidad de poner las otras 3?

ejemplo

```
Exec sp_ejemplo variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5
```

necesito asi

```
Exec sp_ejemplo variable3, variable5
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes darle un valor por defecto a los parámetros no obligatorios, por lo que mencionas, en tu caso, serían todos ya que el requerimiento es que al menos haya dos (cualquiera). Un ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ejemplo 
                       @variable1 INT = NULL, 
                       @variable2 INT = NULL, 
                       @variable3 INT = NULL, 
                       @variable4 INT = NULL,
                       @variable5 INT = NULL
AS
-- CODIGO DEL SP
```

El código anterior a modo de ejemplo, asume que todos los parámetros son `INT`, en realidad serán del tipo que correspondan, lo que sí es importante es que el código del SP considere que puede recibir un valor `NULL` en cualquiera de los parámetros.

Con un SP definido de esta forma, puedes tranquilamente lograr lo que buscas:

```
EXEC sp_ejemplo @variable3 = 1, 
                @variable5 = 2
```